# Android game effects

Tags: android, performance, actionscript, effects

First of all, sorry for my bad English.

I'm going to develop an 2D Android game which is going to have a lot of effects like blood splatting, bomb explosions, etc.. While I was researching, I found out that ActionScript has a lot tutorials and already made effects that look amazing. My question is, can I use (in any way) ActionScript effects in my Android app? Or is it more a ActionScript question, could I export the AS effects in some format and use/import them in the Android app? Off course, performance is also very important, would these effects use a lot CPU/GPU?

Any suggestion would be appropriate.

Comment: You've got better English than most of the people here.

Comment: I loved how you used *witch* instead of *which*...

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are developing your app over AIR, I won't recommend to do so. Have you taken a look at the Android-specific libraries for developing games? For instance [libgdx](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/).

Also, for explosion stuff you basically need to draw particles that go in different directions, which can be easily done using a library like [Tween](http://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine).

Comment: Do you have any experience with libgdx? I'm thinking of porting a game I created from Java to Andoroid. It is a very sloppy implementation, and it would be nice to use a framework to make it more efficient. Would you recommand it? Is it easy to learn? Does it provide help in phisical simulation of 2D objects, and collision detection?

Comment: Thanks for the 'which' correction and the useful answer :) I just google'd for libGDX, it has lot documentation, tutorials, samples.. I will give it a try.

Comment: libgdx is not easy to learn, but it's worthy to give it a try.